# Dont recognize the controller created in one Zend based project and then copy it into another Zend Project

Tags: zend-framework

In Zend project named pro1 I have one module named Admin.In this module I have a controller named DeliveryCentersController.Now I run this project everything is running fine.But Now I have one project pro2 .And I copy the folder Admin of pro1  to pro2 .Now In pro2 I have module named Admin which was created in pro1.Now I run zend command in pro2 to create action as

```
 zf create action act DeliveryCenters -m Admin
```

But it says an error as  An Error Has Occurred Controller DeliveryCenters was not found.To recognize it What should be done??Should change in application.ini file??
When I create another contoller named control in pro2 in Admin module (created in pro1 and copied in pro2) and run zend command to create action in control it runs fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a file named `.zfproject.xml` in the directory above `application`. It contains an XML-document which maps the directory structure.

You'd have to copy the `moduleDirectory`-XML-tag of `Admin` from the `.zfproject.xml` of *Project 1* to *Project 2*.

You probably have to copy the folder `tests/application/modules/admin` from *Project 1* to *Project 2* too. Otherwise there's another ugly error message.